# incompatible types in java

Tags: java

Should I point out that I am a begginer at this?

```
double averageMonthlyTemp() {
    double[] amt = new double[52];
    int sum = 0;
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length - 1; i = i + 7) {
        //where temp is an existiing
        //previously initialized array 
        //of 365 elements, form 0 to 364
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            sum = sum + temp[i + j];
            if (j % 7 == 6) {
                double average = ((double) sum) / 7;
                amt[index] = average;
                index++;
                sum = (int) 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return amt;
}
```

When I try to compile, I get an "incompatible types" error, with the "amt" at `return amt` marked in red. Does somebody know why?

Comment: @Coneone:  looks like it's a `double` to me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method `averageMonthlyTemp` is specified to return some value of type `double`, but your `amt` variable is actually a `double[]`.  Either make `averageMonthlyTmp` return an array of `double`s, or do something like this:

```
double averageMonthlyTmp(int month) {
...
return tmp[month]; // could be made more efficient by only calculating the temperature for one month
}
```

A couple of additional notes about the code:

- Because `j` goes from 0 to 6 inclusive, the `if (j % 7 == 6)` can be replaced with `if (j == 6)`.  Also, it looks like that code (computing the average) can go directly after the second `for` loop.
- In your first for loop, the code will be cleaner if you replace `i = i + 7` with `i += 7`, which will also increase `i` by 7 each time.
- You don't need to put `(int)` before the 0 in the line `sum = (int) 0;`, because Java knows that when you just write `0`, you mean an `int`.

Comment: thak you very much, that really helped :)

Comment: @user2975357, on StackOverflow the response that answers the question best should be marked as "Accepted" using the checkmark by the post.  Otherwise this question continues to appear as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

your method definition for `averageMonthlyTemp` says that it is supposed to return a `double`, that is a single value of datatype `double` but you are returning `amt` which is a double array, that is why the compiler complains. So you can either change the method definition to return an array or return a single value.

Answer (score 1):

the returned value amt is `double[]`. But the function returns only a `double`  value (not an array of double ). so try to rename the function as

```
double [] averagemonthlytemp()
{

}
```